# Did the deity "Horus" pre-date "Horus-Aha"?

Tags: ancient-history, religion, ancient-egypt, prehistory, north-africa

> [Hor-Aha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hor-Aha#Activities_outside_Egypt) (or Aha or Horus Aha) is considered the second pharaoh of the First Dynasty of Egypt by some Egyptologists, others consider him the first one and corresponding to Menes. He lived around the 31st century BC and is thought to have had a long reign.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is that we don't know for certain.  Our understanding of the early evolution of the Egyptian pantheon is limited by the paucity of early texts.  What we can say is neatly summarised by Richard H. Wilkinson in his ambitiously titled [The Complete Gods and Goddesses of Ancient Egypt](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ozgBOQAACAAJ):

> Horus was one of the earliest Egyptian deities.  His name is attested from the beginning of the Dynastic Period and it is probable that early falcon deities such as that shown restraining the 'marsh dwellers' on the Narmer Palette represent this same god.

- Richard H. Wilkinson: The Complete Gods and Goddesses of Ancient Egypt, Thames & Hudson, 2003, p200

---

If the falcon deity depicted on the Narmer Palette is indeed Horus, then the deity does pre-date *Hor-Aha*.

Comment: Horus-Aha was a "predynastic" Pharoah. Or, another way of putting it, from Dynasty 0. "Horus-bird", was a dynastic Pharoah, from Dynasty 1. (or maybe 2). Therefore Horus-bird could not have pre-dated "Horus-Aha", and therefore it is not concluded that Horus the deity predated Horus-Aha

Comment: *Hor-Aha* was a first-dynasty Egyptian King ([the term "Pharaoh" is anachronistic in that context](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/49718/24858) ). *Narmer* was his predecessor (and probably his father).  If the deity portrayed on the Narmer palette is actually Horus, then obviously the deity existed before *Hor-Aha*.

Comment: Do you want to answer the question? I can undo if you wish

Comment: @StevenIanGall I have answered the question. You can accept it, or upvote it, or not as you wish, it won't change the answer.

Comment: It wouldn't be the only time the ancient Egyptians combined multiple gods into one, Amun-Ra being the most obvious one.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Yes, that was a fairly common occurrence.  Another fairly well-known instance was the god *Khenti-Amentiu*, whose name and attributes were combined into the god *Wsjr* (*Osiris*) in the late Old Kingdom / First Intermediate Period.

Comment: @StevenIanGall: If you already had an opinion on this, why ask the question in the first place?